# PDFlib - "leading" option of create_textflow

Tags: pdflib

I'm trying to figure out how to add line spacing without adding spacing above the very first line of textflow.

This code:

```php
$text = 'For more information about the Giant Wing Paper Plane see ' .
    'our Web site <underline=true>www.kraxi-systems.com' .
    'the Giant Wing in a thunderstorm as soon as possible.';
$optlist = 'fontname=Helvetica fontsize=12 encoding=unicode leading=400%';
$tf = $p->create_textflow($text, $optlist);
$result = $p->fit_textflow($tf, 28.346, 28.346, 400, 700, 'fitmethod=nofit');
$p->delete_textflow($tf);
```

results in:

[image]

All is good.

Next, I'm increasing the `leading` option to **400%** as:

```php
$optlist = 'fontname=Helvetica fontsize=12 encoding=unicode leading=400%';
```

And that gives me this:

[image]

**Question**:

How do I keep first paragraph line at the original position and only increase line spacing AFTER it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the "**firstlinedist**" option. The default is **leading**, but you might set this to "**ascender**" or "**capheigt**" or any other value.

Please see PDFlib 9.2 API reference, chapter 5.2, table 5.12 for more details.